# Problem setting page title in content page when title is set in master page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a master page and in its page load event I am appending to the page title:

```
Title = Title + " MyWebsite";
```

Then in a page that uses the previous master page:

```
Title = "Home";
```

What ends up rendering is the value from the master page. A closer look at the debugger shows that it evaluates the Title attribute in my content page, but still says it's an empty string (even though I explicitly have a value set to it.)

Note: Content pages get evaluated before master pages ( I didn't realize this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set page title in `Page_PreInit` event

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
  //set here....
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. Are you able to explain why it worked here but not anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following... and it works as expected.

this.Page.Title = this.Page.Title + " Master Title";